# Add pagelink via ajax in tapestry

Tags: ajax, tapestry

After an ajax call, I want to inject some element (list) in page. For each element of the list, I want to attach t:pagelink. I use PrototypeJs as js framework. Have you any idea? 
I have already test the code below but doesn't work (it not render the t:pagelink)

```js
new Ajax.Request('my_service_url', {
  onSuccess: function(response) {
 response.responseJSON.data.each(function(item){
  var li = '<li>'+
  '<span>'+item.title+'</span>'+
  '<t:pagelink page="examples/navigation/PageLinks2">'+item.link+'</t:pagelink>'+
  '</li>';
  $('mylist').insert(li);
 });
  }
});
```

Comment: Javascript is executed on the client (in the browser) and tapestry templates are rendered on the server. This will never work

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with Tapestry, as Lance Java pointed out, because the Javascript snippet is executed on the client. The client can't submit the `<t:pagelink>` tag to Tapestry for interpretation.

What you need to do instead is use the Ajax semantic of Tapestry, in particular the Zone component. `<t:zone>...</t:zone>` defines a section of your HTML document which will be replaced with a new version, rendered from .tml to html by Tapestry.

So in your `<t:zone>`, add `<t:pagelink>`'s as needed, probably dynamically, based on some condition or in some loop (i.e. with `<t:if>` or `<t:loop>` tags). Then, use some mechanism to send an AJAX event back to Tapestry. One simple option would be to use `<t:actionlink zone="[ID of your zone]">`.

See [here for more info on Zones](http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply but I've found the solution. Just use processReply and it's ok. Indeed, the response needed a bit modification.